# Writing .docx using ReporteRs Package, It Mirrors my Arabic text

Tags: r, arabic

When I write my Poem using `ReporteRs` Package, it mirrors my text like

"عيناكِ غابتا نخيلٍ ساعةَ السحَرْ ،"

it writes it as 
[image]

here's the output from `dput`

```
c("عيناكِ غابتا نخيلٍ ساعةَ السحَرْ ،", "أو شُرفتان راح ينأى عنهما القمر .", 
"عيناك حين تبسمان تورق الكرومْ", "وترقص الأضواء ... كالأقمار في نهَرْ", 
"يرجّه المجذاف وهْناً ساعة السَّحَر", "كأنما تنبض في غوريهما ، النّجومْ ...")
```

here's my code:

```
                        doc <- docx()
                        options( "ReporteRs-fontsize" = 13.5, 
                                 "ReporteRs-default-font" = "Simplified Arabic")
                        doc <- addParagraph(doc,Poem3,par.propertie= parProperties(text.align = "right"))
                        writeDoc(doc, file=Title3)
```

---

I found why it happened but I can't change it. I've to change the directions to "right to left" but I can't find the Argument that do this.